# Creating property with abstract getter doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a property on a abstract class. Instead of stacking `@property` on top of `@abstractmethod` on top of the getter, I'm trying to create the property in the abstract base class manually with the getter as input, which I've decorated with `@abstractmethod`.

With the former approach you need to decorate the getter with `@property` again in the subclass. Whereas the latter approach is slightly nicer for me since now the subclass *only* needs to define a getter method and accessing the property should work.  However, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
import abc

class Foo(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _get_bar(self) -> bool:
        ...

    # not preferred.
    # @property
    # @abc.abstractmethod
    # def BAR(self) -> bool:
    #     ...

    # works!
    # @property
    # def BAR(self) -> bool:
    #     return self._get_bar()

    # doesn't work!
    BAR = property(_get_bar)

class FooBar(Foo):
    # not preferred.
    # @property
    # def BAR(self) -> bool:
    #     ...

    def _get_bar(self) -> bool:
        return True

print(FooBar().BAR)  # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FooBar with abstract methods BAR
```

I'm basing this off what is written in the docs about [`@abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod), the last bit of the code snippet. Or at least I think I am. But it looks like I'm doing something wrong or not understanding properties that well.

Comment: You seem to be saying that doing things the first way **doesn't** mean the subclass only needs to define the getter method — but that's not true.

Comment: @martineau, you're correct. I've edited the description to correctly explain the reasoning for the second approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that this code

```
BAR = property(_get_bar)
```

is executed only once when the body of your base class (`Foo`) is executed -
the `_getbar` in this expression refers to the method defined in *this* class (Foo), which is abstract and empty.

While the form

```
@property
def BAR(self) -> bool:
    return self._get_bar()
```

encapsulates the reference to `_get_bar` inside a method (BAR), which will receive the instance as a parameter, and then retrieve the method from whatever subclass from `Foo` the instance (`self`) happens to be.

The way to fix that is to wrap the property argument in the function call form as a lambda, so that the method is retrieved from the appropriate class on call time:

```
BAR = property(lambda self: self._get_bar())
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was missing. In hindsight, I guess the decorator was just doing `BAR = property(Foo.BAR(self))`.